# Unable to cache JAVA VM while calling Java from NativeC/C++

Tags: java, android, c++, java-native-interface

Please help me to understand JNI programming. Iam new to Java and android. There is a requirement for me to call Java API's from C++. I have followed Stackoverflow url's, still  unable to pass through.

Following is the Java Code which I need to call from native CPP

```java
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class JniTestActivity extends Activity {

    private static String LIB_NAME = "JNItest";

    static {
        System.loadLibrary(LIB_NAME);
    }

    public native void javaCallJNI();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Log.i("onCreate", "Native function begining");
        javaCallJNI();
        Log.i("onCreate", "Native function ending");
    }

    void callFromCPP() {
        Log.i("callFromCPP", "JNI can call JAVA !");
        return;
    }

    void externalcallFromCPP() {
        Log.i("externalcallFromCPP", "3rd Party JNI can call JAVA !");
        return;
    }

}
```

Following is the JNI code which gets JNIENV and calls Java APIs

```cpp
#include <jni.h>
#include <android/log.h>

#define CLASS_NAME  "com/test/jnitest/JniTestActivity"
#define  LOG_TAG    "testjni"
#define  LOGI(...)  __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO,LOG_TAG,__VA_ARGS__)

typedef struct JniMethodInfo_
{
    JNIEnv          *env;
    jclass          clazID;
    jmethodID       methodID;
} JniMethodInfo;

static JavaVM *gJavaVM;
static jobject g_obj;

extern "C" {

    jint JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM *vm, void *reserved)
    {
        LOGI("JNI INIT");
        gJavaVM = vm;

        return JNI_VERSION_1_6;
    }

    JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_test_jnitest_JniTestActivity_javaCallJNI(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj) {
        LOGI("JNI work !");
        jclass clazz = env->FindClass("com/test/jnitest/JniTestActivity");
        if (clazz == 0) {
            LOGI("FindClass error");
            return;
        }

        jmethodID javamethod = env->GetMethodID(clazz, "callFromCPP", "()V");
        if (javamethod == 0) {
            LOGI("GetMethodID error");
            return;
        }
        env->CallVoidMethod(obj, javamethod);
        g_obj = env->NewGlobalRef(obj);
        LOGI("JNI work done !!!!");
    }

    // get env and cache it
    static JNIEnv* getJNIEnv(void)
    {
        if (gJavaVM == NULL) {
            LOGI("Failed to get JNIEnv. VM is NULL");
            return NULL;
        }

        JNIEnv *env = NULL;
        // get jni environment
        jint ret = gJavaVM->GetEnv((void**)&env, JNI_VERSION_1_6);

        switch (ret) {
            case JNI_OK :
                // Success!
                return env;

            case JNI_EDETACHED :

                if (gJavaVM->AttachCurrentThread(&env, NULL) < 0)
                {
                    LOGI("Failed to get the environment using AttachCurrentThread()");
                    return NULL;
                } else {
                    // Success : Attached and obtained JNIEnv!
                    return env;
                }

            case JNI_EVERSION :
                // Cannot recover from this error
                LOGI("JNI interface version 1.4 not supported");
            default :
                LOGI("Failed to get the environment using GetEnv()");
                return NULL;
            }
        }    

        // get class and make it a global reference, release it at endJni().

        static jclass getClassID(JNIEnv *pEnv)
        {
            jclass ret = pEnv->FindClass(CLASS_NAME);
            if (! ret)
            {
                LOGI("Failed to find class of %s", CLASS_NAME);
            }
            return ret;
        }

        JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_test_jnitest_JniTestActivity_javaCallJNI(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj) {
            LOGI("JNI Internal work !");

            jclass clazz = env->FindClass("com/test/jnitest/JniTestActivity");
            if (clazz == 0) {
                LOGI("FindClass error");
                return;
            }
            jmethodID javamethod = env->GetMethodID(clazz, "callFromCPP", "()V");
            if (javamethod == 0) {
                LOGI("GetMethodID error");
                return;
            }
            env->CallVoidMethod(obj, javamethod);

            LOGI("JNI Internal work done !!!!");
        }

        static bool getStaticMethodInfo(JniMethodInfo &methodinfo, const char *methodName, const char *paramCode)
        {
            LOGI("In MethodInfo::JNI external work !");
            jmethodID methodID = 0;
            JNIEnv *pEnv = 0;
            bool bRet = false;

            do 
            {
                pEnv = getJNIEnv();
                if (! pEnv)
                {
                    break;
                }

                jclass clazID = getClassID(pEnv);
                methodID = pEnv->GetStaticMethodID(clazID, methodName, paramCode);
                if (! methodID)
                {
                    LOGI("Failed to find static method id of %s", methodName);
                    break;
                }

                methodinfo.clazID = clazID;
                methodinfo.env = pEnv;
                methodinfo.methodID = methodID;

                bRet = true;
            } while (0);

            return bRet;
        }
        //Call from external app which is compiled with this as shared library.
        void ThirdpartyjavaCallJNI ( )
        {
            LOGI("JNI external work !");
            JniMethodInfo methodInfo;

            if (! getStaticMethodInfo(methodInfo, "externalcallFromCPP", "()V"))
            {
                LOGI("Failed to find the method!");
                return ;
            }

            methodInfo.env->CallVoidMethod(g_obj, methodInfo.methodID);
            methodInfo.env->DeleteLocalRef(methodInfo.clazID);

            LOGI("external call from cpp");
        }
    }
```

Here I am doing two things

1. Calling Java API from JNI (C++)
2. Calling Java API from native app which is compiled with shared library.

My test app code where I am getting error

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include "JniTestActivity.h"

int main()
{
    printf("APP: Hello TestJNI\n");
    ThirdpartyjavaCallJNI();
}
```

I am able to get success in first case. But when I do the API call in second case, I am getting JAVAVM as null. Following is the snippet:

```
LOGI("Failed to get JNIEnv. VM is NULL");
```

Please suggest me where I am doing wrong.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html

Answer (score 1):

Your code expects to be able to obtain a Java VM from `JavaVM *gJavaVM`, which is initialized by `JNI_OnLoad`.

But that method is only called when your shared library is loaded from Java through JNI. If a native application loads your library, the `JNI_OnLoad` hook will never be called, and you won't have access to a VM. There probably isn't even a VM running in that process!

If you want to be able to call Java code from a library used by a native application, you will need to arrange for a Java environment to be created and exposed within that process, assuming such a thing is even possible on your platform.

Comment: Thanks Stuart for reply. Do you mean i need to create JNI Environment in native code. JNI_CreateJVM from Native, through that i need to call Java API's. Is my understanding correct ?

Comment: HI, I have googled and find something interesting project CoCos2dx. How come they are getting JNI Environment with the same mechanism. Please find the following project  https://github.com/nokia-developer/cocos2d-x-qt/tree/master/CocosDenshion/android